# problems specifying user password with puppet (+vagrant) on precise32 virtualbox

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant

I'm using vagrant+puppet to provision a `precise32` VirtualBox server to add users programatically. I've got everything working but I can't seem to set the password automatically by puppet. Here's my puppet script:

```ruby
package { "ruby-shadow":
  name => "libshadow-ruby1.8",
  ensure => installed,
}
user { 'biff':
  home       => '/home/biff',
  shell      => '/bin/bash',
  uid        => 201,
  managehome => 'true',
  password   => '$6$kxHLEuHW$zHRAZcVLu0XzukqU79bT.PEg./FfcloJiWmlH2rf.Lmnyke7uAaHkQTXvErqikWeraSiHFBwDSMDV4hRImqjr7.',
  groups     => ['sudo', ],
  requires   => Package['ruby-shadow'],
}
```

To get the hash `$6$kx...`, I logged into the virtual machine, ran `sudo passwd biff` to set the password with the system, and then copied the hashed password (second field in `/etc/shadow`) into the puppet script above. After removing the user to reset the password and rerunning the puppet script, the password isn't set and I can't login at all:

```bash
[precise32]$ sudo grep biff /etc/shadow
biff:!:15862:0:99999:7:::
```

In fact, it looks like the user `biff` has been locked out of the system ([/etc/shadow explanation](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/)). Do I have the correct hash set as the `password` variable? How do you figure out what that is?

It looks like one approach might be to run [`usermod` after the fact to set the password](https://serverfault.com/questions/350230/how-can-i-have-puppet-only-set-password-when-creating-a-user), but that seems to be against the entire point of using puppet in the first place. Any ideas?

Comment: anyone care to comment what the down-vote was for?

Comment: working this exact issue now...if you were able to solve it i'd love to hear how...

Comment: I was never able to figure out how to set the `password` argument as above, but I was able to get it to work using the `usermod` trick [see last link at the end]. If you get it to work, please post your answer; I'm stumped!

Comment: Mine ended up being an issue with the test box i was using; the lib crypt library wasn't installed correctly.  I downloaded a different vagrant box and it worked beautifully.

Comment: care to post your solution? I thought I installed lib crypt but perhaps I'm mistaken. Thanks!

Comment: I did already. I used `vagrant box add "new box name" http://boxurl.com` and pulled a new box.  You can find a whole bunch of them at http://www.vagrantbox.es.

Answer (score 0):

The vagrant box you're using may be using ruby libraries in `/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/1.8/` and not using any system-installed ruby libraries. Check if your vagrant box has a file at `/etc/profile.d/vagrant_ruby.sh`. If it does, that's what's overriding which `puppet` command to use, which then determines which ruby libraries to use. Try removing that file ;) If things still work (after installing puppet and libshadow-ruby to the system), repackage the box with `vagrant package` and re-use that as your `precise32` box.

I'm sure there were many good reasons to usr `/opt/vagrant_ruby`, but it's missing a pretty important library and makes it a little confusing when using other tools inside the box which pull in ruby libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet will fail to set the password unless the 
`libshadow` gem is present, as this is required to work with shadow 
passwords. IIRC there is an error message about the provider.
`libshadow` requires `mkmf.rb` to be installed, which can be found in the packages **libruby2.0, ruby1.9.1-dev or ruby1.8-dev** (depending on your ruby version)

I have this in my manifest:

 `package {
    "ruby1.9.1-dev": 
      ensure => installed;
    "libshadow": 
      ensure => installed, 
      require => Package['ruby1.9.1-dev'], 
      provider => gem;
 }`